# Service Bus for Windows Server authorization

Tags: windows, azure, servicebus

I don't understand the security behind the Service Bus for Windows Server.

```
connBuilder.Endpoints.Add(new UriBuilder() { Scheme = "sb", Host =
ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNamespace }.Uri);

MessagingFactory messageFactory MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connBuilder.ToString());
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connBuilder.ToString());
```

with that messageFactory and namespaceManager I can create queues and send stuff right away. Where is the authentication process or authorization being done ? I know there is the possibility to provide some token and stuff. But with this piece of code I can create and send things without the token. How is it possible ?

Comment: Could be that the Service Bus and your application are running under the same login? I had this scenario in development and it worked as you noted. But installing it on a server with the app running under a different login to the bus's login, I am now facing the need for proper authentication.

Comment: Well, that was it my friend ! thanks

Comment: Great. I'll rephrase it a bit and put it as an answer. You can accept if you like. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the Service Bus and your application are running under the same login. I had this scenario in development and it worked as you noted. But installing it on a server with the app running under a different login to the bus's login, I am now facing the need for proper authentication.